# Symfony api platform use controller

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

i use the api platform in symfony 4 and i have question

I would like to know how to create a controller with api platform and create 2 route in get

I show you what I have done for now:

my controller :

```
/**
 * @var UnedicPublicationOrderRepository
 */
private $publicationOrderRepository;

public function __construct(UnedicPublicationOrderRepository $publicationOrderRepository)
{
    $this->publicationOrderRepository = $publicationOrderRepository;
}


public function __invoke()
{
    $cible = $this->publicationOrderRepository->findAll();

    return $cible;
}
```

and my entity for publication

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * UnedicPublicationOrderController
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"get"={"method"="GET"}},
 *     itemOperations={
 *     "get"={"method"="GET", "path"="/publication/{cible}"},
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 * @ORM\Entity
```

Comment: i dont have solution :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a specific controller for a custom operation you need to add the controller as an option

```
use App\Controller\UnedicPublicationOrderController;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "customGet"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "path"="/publication/{cible}",
 *             "controller"=UnedicPublicationOrderController::class,
 *         },
 *     },
```

A complete example can be seen in the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#recommended-method)

Answer (score 5):

if your controller return a collection you need to add the route in collectionOperations otherwise register it in itemOperations section.
Don't forget to import the controller class in entity.

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Controllers\UnedicPublicationOrderController; // import controller
/**
 * UnedicPublicationOrderController
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
            "get"={"method"="GET"},
            "get_publication_order"={
               "path"="/publication_orders/all",
               "method"="GET",
               "controller"=UnedicPublicationOrderController::class     
             }
   },
 *     itemOperations={
 *           "get"={"method"="GET", "path"="/publication/{cible}"},
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 * @ORM\Entity
```

you can also check the docs for more examples [creating-custom-operations-and-controllers](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers)

Comment: how do i create my own function without necessarily going through the __invoke method?

Comment: @CrownBackend  You can create a usual Symfony controller and define the route in routes.yaml